# Fetching website's logs using Apache Kafka and process it using Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am new to Apache Kafka.I was able to run console Producers and Consumers but now I want to process the logs of my friend's  website using Apache Kafka and Spark Streaming. Firstly I had started the zookeeper service using-:
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties

After that I had started the broker using-:
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties

and then created a topic.But after that I became confused that where to run the producer(bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test) command either on my laptop or on the client side?
Please help.

Comment: what you want to do with producer ?

Comment: I want to fetch the logs of my friend's website.So I want to write the producer code and run it on my friend's machine.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt, that using the `kafka-consule-consumer.sh` is a good choice... It is only designed for testing during development...

However, if you have single log file, you can pipe the log file into the producer like this:

```
tail -n +1 -f webServer.log | bin/kafka-consule-consumer.sh --broker-list <broker>:9092 --topic test
```

Of course, you must run this command on the web server machine.